# How do I get json.net to exclude nulls when deseralizing a collection?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON that I am getting back that potentially gets back nulls as part of the values. How can I, or is there even a way, to exclude those nulls from the collection?

```
      {
     "id": "5551212",
     "from": {
        "name": "Message creator",
        "start_time": "2011-10-21T22:00:00",
        "end_time": "2011-10-23T17:00:00",
        "location": "area 51",
        "id": "2121212122"
     },
     "to": {
        "data": [
          {
              "name": "Jay-Z",
              "id": "77777"
           },
           {
              "name": "Bill Murray",
              "id": "88888"
           },
           null,
           {
              "name": "Anthony Hopkins",
              "id": "99999"
           }
        ]
     },
     "message": "Some message from somewhere",
     "updated_time": "2011-09-19T23:53:51+0000",
     "unread": 1,
     "unseen": 0
  }
```

Notice between Bill Murray and Anthony Hopkins the null that is returned. Thanks.

Comment: Null has no meaning now? News to me!

Comment: I never said that null didn't have meaning. According to the API here (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm) you can pass settings to include or ignore nulls. So based on that, there should be a mechanism to exclude them.

Comment: @leppie not serializing null or empty arrays will reduce document size in nosql databases, so yeah its kinda important

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply decorate properties/fields that can be null with

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

For more info on how to reduce json size: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx

Comment: I will give this a try. Will up vote once I get working.

Comment: Sure thing. It's the recommended way as per the author himself as mentioned in the blog post

Comment: You can also set the null value handling on a wider scale by changing the property on `SerializerSettings`.  For example, on Web API you might do: `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` in your `WebApiConfig` class.

Answer (score -4):

I would use convert method to get an XML string.

```
// jsonString is populated from your....
XmlNode xmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString);
```

The null value in XML would be like:

```
...<data></data>...
```

which can be easily removed by string replacement or XML filtering.

Comment: XML has nothing to do with the OP's question.